# Pendulum with freely-moving support mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, non-linear-systems

> A  pendulum has a mass at the point of suspension which is free to move along a horizontal line. Find:
>
> 1. state-space portraits, and
> 2. small amplitude solutions (analytically)

Can Anyone help me solve the following two equations
$$(M+m)l\ddot\theta+ml\dot\theta^2-ml\dot\theta=-(M+m)/g$$
$$Ml\ddot\theta+ml\dot\theta^2\theta+(M+m)g=0$$
where $M=$ mass of the support and $m=$ mass of the bob.

Comment: Regrettably this question looks like it will be closed for being in breach of the Homework Policy. I do not think it is. In any case it might get better answers on Mathematics SE because you are asking how to solve coupled differential equations.

Comment: A state-space (or phase space) portrait plots velocity variable $\dot\theta$ against position variable $\theta$. The obvious next step is to eliminate $\ddot\theta$.